# node-latex image rendering

Tags: node.js, latex

I'm trying to use LaTeX's graphicx package to include a JPEG image in a template, but the package doesn't seem to render that image. I might be omitting something of course, but I have included my code below for consideration.

I am using a containerised Ubuntu 14.04 instance in Cloud 9, texlive-full package and node v6.10.2.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var input = process.argv[2];
var output = process.argv[3];
var temp = [];

fs.readFile(input, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('>>> Tex file imported.');
  temp.push(data);
  var options = { 'command': 'pdflatex' };
  require('latex')(temp, options).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(output));
  console.log('>>> Tex file built.');
});
```

My tex file is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article} \usepackage{graphicx} \begin{document} 
\begin{center} \includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.jpg}
\newline \Large NOTICE
\end{center}
\sffamily Account Number: \textit{12345678} \newline
\newline MR A TEST
\newline 2 THE STREET
\newline FARNBERRY
\newline CLOUD TOWN
\newline GU15 3AA \newline
\newline Amount: 1078.52
\newline Financial Year: \textbf{2017}
\newline
\newline \small{Footer text}
\end{document}
```

If I compile this tex file from the terminal using the command `>pdflatex filename.tex` the image renders fine in a PDF. Are you able to help me in rendering the included image please?

Thanks.

Comment: I didnt catch your error. When you make pdf out .tex file, your image is not displaying?

Comment: Hi @mtkilic yes, when I run the node app including the input file and output file as arguments like this `>node app.js texfile.tex output.pdf` the PDF is created, but the logo.jpg is not included.

Comment: More likely, your `texfile.tex` and `jpg` is not in same folder.

Comment: I can confirm that they are in the same folder, as when I run the terminal command `>pdflatex filename.tex` on the same tex file the jpg renders fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the case that the latex run is done in some temporary directory and the image is not found there. Try changing the `\includegraphics` to have the *full path* of the image:

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{/full/path/to/directory/containing/logo.jpg}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your `.tex` file to this and give try? Also if you have perl installed, you can use the command `latexmk -pdf`

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}  
\begin{center} 
\includegraphics[scale=1]{logo.jpg}
\newline \Large NOTICE
\end{center}
\sffamily Account Number: \textit{12345678} \newline
\newline MR A TEST
\newline 2 THE STREET
\newline FARNBERRY
\newline CLOUD TOWN
\newline GU15 3AA \newline
\newline Amount: 1078.52
\newline Financial Year: \textbf{2017}
\newline
\newline \small{Footer text}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @mtkilic adding the figure attribute hasn't helped. It compiles fine manually from the terminal, but not from the nodejs script. I think perhaps there is a bug in the npm module **node_latex**? What I am trying to do is create a proof of concept that repetitive document production could be automated using a parameterised latex template. So far it works if I don't include images :-) Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @MattLindsay I had to create 10s of pdf file from png files for documentation last week. I used Python and latex, I upload my script to github, maybe this will help you. https://github.com/mtkilic/Python-useful-scripts/blob/master/latex_file.py  I dont know much about node.js sorry cant be much help :/

Comment: Hi @mtkilic thanks for the repo link, I think that will be useful. In the meantime I've switched to using gulp-pdflatex2 npm package and it works great.

Comment: @MattLindsay happy to hear you found something is working out for you :)